# Get modified key with SDL2

Tags: sdl2, keyboard

If I poll keyboard events with SDL2 all I get is the pressed key and the modifiers. But I am using [Neo](http://neo-layout.org/) and have some keys like Esc and arrow keys on a different layer which means that e.g. `Mod4+i` is the same as the left arrow key.

How can I get the modified key from SDL2?

The same problem occurs to me when I want to handle special chars which are located on different keys on different keyboard layouts (`/` for example has a dedicated key on US layout while on German layout it is located at `Shift+7`).

I already found the text input mode, but this seams rather unfitting as one gets a string instead of a single key.

Edit: formatting

Edit 2: I just found another problem .. SDL doesn't recognize `Mod4` so when pressing `Mod4` plus another key, the `mod` field is still `0`. Other modifiers like `Shift` work.

Comment: Have you tried using scancodes? I feel like they *might* solve atleast some of your problems.

Comment: But that way I have to handle different keyboard layouts different ...
Edit: Also Mod4 is not recognized which doesn't allow me to handle this by hand.

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with Neo (the website is in German), but it does seem a little weird that SDL doesn't recognize the modifiers. Could you perhaps clarify how Neo works, and where in terms of event managing it does its magic?

Comment: I can only speak for Linux ... there it is an official XServer keyboard map using the Xkbmap levels (I'm not really familiar with how the XServer handles different levels), so it should be no magic.

Comment: What's your SDL version?

Comment: I've got 2.0.4.

Comment: All right. This seems quite odd to me. Could you try setting the `SDL_HINT_IME_INTERNAL_EDITING` hint?

Comment: That did not change anything ... by the way thank you very much for helping!

Comment: Hmm, okay. I'm currently on my mobile, but I'll try to do more investigating tomorrow when on a PC. This is quite interesting